# Python 3 installation for Maya 2019 or higher

Tags: python, python-3.x, maya

Is there a way of installing python 3 in Maya 2019 or higher versions?

I know there's some information about this on some forums but I still hope for a positive answer:))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Autodesk Maya 2022 | 2023, `Python 3` is now a [part of Maya](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2022/ENU/Maya-WhatsNewPR/files/GUID-DF43840B-4DB1-43F8-BFD1-97D8D031B91D-htm.html?us_oa=akn-us&us_si=e5414f3d-1648-4f0f-8d47-7077c96f7374&us_st=python%203).

Maya 2023 uses Python 3 [exclusively](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2023/ENU/Maya-WhatsNewPR/files/GUID-DF43840B-4DB1-43F8-BFD1-97D8D031B91D-htm.html).

Python 3 [can't properly work](https://discourse.techart.online/t/maya-2019-with-python-3-0/9815) in Maya 2019 | 2020.